# PHP WordPress file_exists not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin and trying to embed something if the file/folder exists.
This perfectly works in php but not within WP. Any help would be appreciated.
This code is in the admin area under the plugin's setting page. And yes, I'm sure the path to the folder is correct.

```
$filename = plugins_url('../admin_side/webmailing/install/', __FILE__);

if (file_exists($filename)) { 

echo 'something';

 else {

echo 'something else';

}
```

Comment: What is `$filename` being set to?

Comment: the path to the folder?

Comment: Well, clearly it's not or it'd be working :) have you echo'd the contents to check?

Comment: yes I did, if I echo it I get the url for the folder

Comment: just to mention that I get a blank page and no errors

Comment: A blank page? Not even any of the echo's in the script?

Comment: yeah, that's weird. Must be something wrong with if statement. I doesn't work even with if(3+3=6)

Comment: You have a PHP error of some kind - check the logs or turn on error reporting

Comment: Does your PHP work in general? If you just make it echo out a word, is it echoe'd?

Comment: @Bulk, got it. syntax error. Sorry guys.. I needed bracket before else

Comment: Doh! I missed that too hah

Comment: but the file_exists still doesn't work right. It seems like he can't detect if the file exists even though it does...

Comment: ok, I got it, I need to use plugin_dir_path() not plugins_url()

Comment: You should either delete this question or update it with your comment above as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_exists` expects a file path but you're passing it a URL.

Change:

```
$filename = plugins_url('../admin_side/webmailing/install/', __FILE__);
```

To:

```
$filename = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin_side/webmailing/install/';
```

Comment: No it doesn't.  You can use relative or network paths.  See http://php.net/file_exists

Comment: Slight mixup of terminology on my part but the answer remains valid.  The issue is because the user is passing in a URL and not a file path. The code provided resolves the issue.